# Lacking numbers in some pages

Tags: page-numbering

I´m using `report` (Koma script) and `\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic} \setcounter{page}{1}` in LaTeX code boxes where I need roman and arabic numbers respectively.

However, some pages randomly lack numbers. Some of them have pictures but others don't. What could be the reason? Any possible solution is well appreciated :)

Comment: We would need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) in order to adequately address this problem.

Comment: It looks there is `\thispagestyle{empty}` command in the process. Please edit your post and add fully compilable example. If you would like to refer to pictures, please use those included in the [`mwe`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mwe) package.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the MWE in my question. Here is the link: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/5za1s8aq0gor9u1/K3sXCifOPE  @Malipivo

Answer (score 6):

KOMA-Script uses page style `empty` for pages generated by `\cleardoublepage` since version 3.00 (see d[ocumentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/doc/scrguien.pdf), section "3.13. Interleaf Pages"). This can be changed by option `cleardoublepage`:

```
\KOMAoptions{cleardoublepage=plain}
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[twoside,openright]{scrreprt}
\KOMAoptions{cleardoublepage=plain}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Foo}
\chapter{Bar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If I want a single side document, not twoside, how would the code be? Sorry if it´s a silly question, I´m new with Lyx.

Comment: Try to remove `twoside,` from the first line.

Comment: @JouvettGarcia: Without a MWE I had to speculate what might have caused the empty page style. With `twoside` `\cleardoublepage` can create empty pages, whose page style can be configured as shown above.

Comment: Sorry for not posting the MWE in my question. Here is the link: dropbox.com/sh/5za1s8aq0gor9u1/K3sXCifOPE @HeikoOberdiek

Comment: @JouvettGarcia: I don't have/use Lyx.

Comment: Nevermind, I just fixed it by using "Custom Header/Footerlines". @HeikoOberdiek